# How to change Hibernate Mapping , without crashing the Database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two Entitys.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EX.EXAMPLE")
public class Entity
{

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private long id;


  @OneToOne
  private Entity2 stuff1;
  @OneToOne
  private Entity2 stuff2;
  @OneToOne
  private Entity2 stuff3;
}
```

And the second is the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EX.EXAMPLE2")
public class Entity2
{

  @Id 
  private long stuff;

}
```

Know i need to change the current id (Stuff) to a new One. I added a new columne ID to table. How to change/migrate the foreign Keys and make the new Columne ID a uniqe Key ?
Is it possibe to do it with Hibernate ? or is there a way with MYSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to modify the primary key. do it in a different approach. and why you have created three @OneToOne relations with the same entity? this is redundant and they are the same. it's not necessary to make relation for each object